# How to split and generate elements in a list to a datafarme

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Let's say I have a list as following,

```
l1 =    ['SAP_QGF_126151_HFM_1_MOB_T_GFG_XZY_S7_L001_R1_001_MM_1.gz',
         'SAP_QGF_126151_HFM_1_MOB_T_GFG_XZY_S7_L001_R2_001_MM_1.gz',
         'SAP_QGF_126151_HFM_2_MOB_T_GFG_XZY_S7_L002_R1_001_MM_1.gz',
         'SAP_QGF_126151_HFM_2_MOB_T_GFG_XZY_S7_L002_R2_001_MM_1.gz']
```

And I wanna convert the above list into a data frame, with four columns.
First I wanna split it on `_` and use the 5th string as the first column, 4th string as second column and the whole string of the first and second elements in the list as the third and fourth column based on the if condition.

And I tried to generate them form lists,

```
col1    = [x.split('_')[5] for x in l1]
col2    = [x.split('_')[4] for x in l1]
col3     = [x.split('_')[10] for x in l1 if x == "L001"]
col4     = [x.split('_')[10] for x in l1 if x == "L002"]
```

However, for `col3` and `col4` it is not return anything with if condition.

I try to convert all the list using the following one-liner :

`pd.DataFrame( {'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3': col3, 'col4':col4 })`

In the end, I aim to have a data frame as, **My desired output**

```
col1  col2 col3 col4 
MOB   1   SAP_QGF_126151_HFM_1_MOB_T_GFG_XZY_S7_L001_R1_001_MM_1.gz SAP_QGF_126151_HFM_1_MOB_T_GFG_XZY_S7_L001_R2_001_MM_1.gz      
MOB   2   SAP_QGF_126151_HFM_1_MOB_T_GFG_XZY_S7_L002_R1_001_MM_1.gz SAP_QGF_126151_HFM_1_MOB_T_GFG_XZY_S7_L002_R2_001_MM_1.gz
```

So I need the first element from list `l1` as it is in the `col3` and second element in `col4` in the first `row`. So as the third element in `col3` and 4th element in `col4` and these both must be in the second `row`.

Any suggestions or pointers are appreciated

Comment: for `col3` and `col4` `x` is the entire string, so it will never be equal to that partial string.

Comment: hmm, Ok , in this case. How can I procced this tricky case

Comment: `col3 = [x if x.split('_')[10] == "L001" else '' for x in l1]` and `col4 = [x if x.split('_')[10] == "L002" else '' for x in l1]`

Comment: I would just `pd.DataFrame([x.split('_') for x in l])` then select the columns you need. Can you give an example of your desired output? I'm not quite sure what you need for `col4` and `col3`

Comment: I have an example of desired out in my question

Comment: Though in your output it seems like `col3` has both L001 and L002, though your logic seems to not want that . Is it perhaps supposed to be R1 and R2? That's the only field where the  sets of strings seem to disagree.

Comment: yes, but both of them are in different rows. I need both `L001` and `L002` in both  col3 and col4. However, in different rows. As it is mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
col1 = [x.split('_')[5] for x in l1]
col2 = [x.split('_')[4] for x in l1]
col3 = [x for x in l1 if x.split('_')[10] == "L001"]
col4 = [x for x in l1 if x.split('_')[10] == "L002"]
pd.DataFrame( {'col1': col1[:len(col3)], 'col2': col2[:len(col3)], 'col3': col3, 'col4':col4 })
```